# I Can't figure out what I must push to the stack before calling `_getch` in FASM

Tags: assembly, fasm, sasm

I'm using the [SASM IDE by Dmitry Manushin](http://dman95.github.io/) to write a program in FASM. My code is as follows:

```
format ELF

section '.data' writeable
    msg db 'Hello, world of Flat ASM!',  0Dh, 0Ah, 00h ; terminate with null string
    buffer rb 20
    inp_buf_size rw 1
    pkey db 'Press any key to exit ...', 0h
    formatStr db "%s", 0

section '.text' executable
public _main
extrn _printf
extrn _getch
extrn _getche
_main:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    push msg ; push message onto the stack
    push formatStr ; push formatter onto the stack
    call _printf ; call the printf method to print the message
    add esp, 8 ; clean up
    xor eax, eax
    ; press any key to exit
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    push pkey ; push message onto the stack
    push formatStr ; push formatter onto the stack
    call _printf ; call the printf method to print the message
    add esp, 8
    xor eax, eax
    
    ; get input here, using getch or getche (how? What must be pushed)
    ; mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ; push buffer
    ; call _getch
    ; add esp, 8
    ; xor eax, eax
    
    ret
```

Printing the "Hello, world ..." and "Press any key ..." code works as expected. What I'm stuck on is how I go about getting the program to wait for/read a single character into the buffer using `_getch`. (What, if anything, should I push onto the stack before calling `_getch`?) I've tried moving values into `ah` and using interrupts, but this causes the program to crash.

- **OS:** Windows 10 x86_64
- **Assembly language:** FASM (as included with SASM) -- `$SOURCE$ $PROGRAM.OBJ$ -s $LSTOUTPUT$`
- ** Mode:** x86
- **Linker options:** `$PROGRAM.OBJ$ $MACRO.OBJ$ -g -o $PROGRAM$ -m32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on here `format ELF` tells FASM to create a Linux object file. Which feels a little odd because you are running Windows. But what makes it work is that SASM  is using the MinGW version of the Linux gcc toolchain to create the executable. Which means you can write some Linux assembly but not everything can be Linux syntax.

Another issue is that `getch` is not POSIX so could be causing problems, use `getchar` instead.

And lastly windows does not exit programs by using return values in eax. The

```
xor eax, eax
ret
```

part will hang in Windows because of this. A safe way to do it is `call _ExitProcess` passing it 0 on the stack.

It appears that SASM expects any input to be entered into the input box beforehand and because of that does not wait for the `_getchar`. I left it in to show how it would work if SASM did not do this. Running similar code assembled directly using FASM works as expected.

Putting that all together this we get this:

```
format ELF

section '.data' writeable
    msg db 'Hello, world of Flat ASM!',  0Dh, 0Ah, 00h
    pkey db 'Press any key to exit ...', 0h
    formatStr db "%s", 0

public _main
extrn _printf
extrn _getchar
extrn _ExitProcess

section '.text' executable

_main:
    push msg 
    push formatStr
    call _printf

    push pkey
    push formatStr
    call _printf

    call _getchar
    push 0
    call _ExitProcess
```

I removed the stack code for simplicity as this is only a hello world.

Comment: There is no need to push, `mov rcx, 0` followed by `call    ExitProcess` does it without stack

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to figure out how to get SASM to behave on Windows when I found your question, after I wrote my other answer I stumbled upon a way for it to be able to use native Windows FASM syntax. In the Build options check the "Disable linking" box and change the `$PROGRAM.OBJ$` "Assembly options" parameter to `$PROGRAM$`. This will cause it to use the Windows FASM.exe to assemble an your exe and skip the Linux style object creation and gcc linking.

A big negative of this is that the debugger no longer works which is a deal killer for me.

To show what Windows FASM code looks like here's my hello world:

```
format PE console
entry _main
include '%fasm_inc%/win32a.inc'

section '.data' data readable

hello db 'Hello world!', 0

section '.text' code readable executable

_main:
    invoke _printf, hello
    invoke _getchar
    push eax
    invoke _putchar
    invoke _ExitProcess, 0

section '.idata' import data readable

library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll',\
    msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'

import kernel32,\
        _ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
import msvcrt,\
        _printf, 'printf',\
        _getchar, 'getchar',\
        _putchar, 'putchar'
```

I added the `_putchar` to show that the `_getchar` is using the text in the input box and that SASM does not wait for user input.

Comment: Not having the debugger available to me is going to be a stumbling block, especially since I am learning FASM,so I'll stick with the MinGW toolchain for now.

Comment: I've just tried to build this (with both Fresh and SASM), but the compiler/linker keeps complaining about not being able to find `win32.a.inc`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60349554/2225787) given by [@nash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98145/nash), here's the ELF64 (x86_64 for GNU/Linux) version:

```
format ELF64

section '.data' writeable
    msg db 'Hello, world of Flat ASM x86_64!', 0Dh, 0Ah, 00h
    pkey db 'Press any key to exit ...', 08h, 00h 
    formatStr db "%s", 0

section '.text' executable
public main
extrn printf
extrn getchar
extrn ExitProcess

main:
    mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging
    sub rsp, 32
    and rsp, -16
    mov rcx, formatStr
    mov rdx, msg
    call printf
    mov rdx, pkey
    mov rcx, formatStr
    call printf
    call getchar
    mov rsp, rbp
    xor eax, eax ; might not need this
    push 0
    call ExitProcess
    
    ret
```

*Note 1:* For x86_64, remove the preceding underscores from the 32-bit version and change format to `ELF64`.

*Note 2:* Although this will run through the SASM IDE (if you type <Enter> in the input box before compiling and running it), it will *not* run directly on Windows through the CMD console. You'll probably have to link in a Cygwin DLL for that or place it in a directory under the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Thanks, nash!